# Generating all combinations of 6 Xs with 3 Qs in Haskell

Tags: haskell, combinations

I am trying to generate a list of all strings that consist of 6 Xs and 3 Qs.

A subset of the list I am trying to generate is as follows:

```
["XXXXXXQQQ", "XQXXQXXQX", "QXQXQXXXX",...
```

What is a good way to go about this?

Comment: Is this supposed to scale past 6 Xs and 3 Qs? A naive approach looks easy - but there is a more efficient dynamic programming solution.

Comment: I am trying to scale this to bigger `n` where there are `n*n-n` Xs and `n` Qs. The above example is just with `n=3`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a dynamic programming solution using `Data.Array`. `mem` just stores memoized values.

```
import Data.Array

strings :: Int -> Int -> [String]
strings n m = strings' n m
  where
    mem :: Array (Int,Int) [String]
    mem = array ((0,0),(n,m)) [ ((i,j), strings' i j) | i <- [0..n], j <- [0..m] ]

    strings' 0 m = [replicate m 'X']
    strings' n 0 = [replicate n 'Q']
    strings' n m = (('Q':) <$> mem ! (n-1,m)) ++ (('X':) <$> mem ! (n,m-1))
```

Answer (score 3):

The naive solution is to recursively choose one of `X` or `Q` until we run out of choices to make. This is especially convenient when using the list monad to model the nondeterministic choice, and leads to quite short code:

```
stringsNondet m 0 = [replicate m 'X']
stringsNondet 0 n = [replicate n 'Q']
stringsNondet m n = do
    (char, m', n') <- [('X', m-1, n), ('Q', m, n-1)]
    rest <- stringsNondet m' n'
    return (char:rest)
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that it does a lot of extra work. If we choose an `X` and then choose a `Q`, the continuations are the same as if we had chosen a `Q` and then an `X`, but these continuations will be recomputed in the above. (And similarly for other choice paths that lead to shared continuations.)

Alec has posted a dynamic programming solution which solves this problem by introducing a recursively-defined array to share the subcomputations. I like this solution, but the recursive definition is a bit mind-bending. The following solution is also a dynamic programming solution -- subcomputations are also shared -- but uses no hand-written recursion. It does make use of standard recursive patterns (`map`, `zip`, `iterate`, `++`, and `!!`) but notably does not require "tying the knot" as Alec's solution does.

As a warmup, let's discuss the type of the function of interest to us:

```
step :: [[String]] -> [[String]]
```

The final result of interest to us is `[String]`, a collection of strings with a fixed number `m` of `'X'`s and a fixed number `n` of `'Q'`s. The `step` function will expect a collection of results, all of the same length, and will assume that the result at index `m` has `m` copies of `'X'`. It will also produce a result with these properties, and where each result is one longer than the input results.

We implement `step` by producing two intermediate `[[String]]`s, one with an extra `'X'` compared to the input results and one with an extra `'Q'`. These two intermediates can then be zipped together with a little "stutter" to represent the slight difference in `'X'` count between them. Thus:

```
step css = zipWith (++)
    ([[]] ++ map (map ('X':)) css)
    (map (map ('Q':)) css ++ [[]])
```

The top-level function is now easy to write: we simply index into the iterated version of `step` by the length of the final string we want, then index into the list of results we get that way by the number of `'X'`s we want.

```
strings m n = iterate step [[[]]] !! (m+n) !! m
```

A bonus of this approach is the single, aesthetically pleasing base case of `[[[]]]`.

Comment: @Alec Our solutions are pretty close in performance. On my machine, `stringsDmwit 11 11` takes 0.44s and 62MB while `stringsAlec 11 11` takes 0.63s and 148MB. At time of writing, all other solutions suggested are much less performant.

Answer (score 1):

Use `permutations` and `nub` functions from `Data.List`:

```
Prelude Data.List> nub $ permutations "XXXXXXQQQ"
["XXXXXXQQQ","QXXXXXXQQ","XQXXXXXQQ","XXQXXXXQQ","XXXQXXXQQ","XXXXQXXQQ","XXXXXQXQQ","QQXXXXXXQ","QXQXXXXXQ","QXXQXXXXQ","QXXXQXXXQ","QXXXXQXXQ","QXXXXXQXQ","XQQXXXXXQ","XQXQXXXXQ","XQXXQXXXQ","XQXXXQXXQ","XQXXXXQXQ","XXQQXXXXQ","XXQXQXXXQ","XXQXXQXXQ","XXQXXXQXQ","XXXQQXXXQ","XXXQXQXXQ","XXXQXXQXQ","XXXXQQXXQ","XXXXQXQXQ","XXXXXQQXQ","QQQXXXXXX","QQXQXXXXX","QQXXQXXXX","QQXXXQXXX","QQXXXXQXX","QQXXXXXQX","QXQQXXXXX","XQQQXXXXX","XQQXQXXXX","XQQXXQXXX","XQQXXXQXX","XQQXXXXQX","QXQXQXXXX","QXQXXQXXX","QXQXXXQXX","QXQXXXXQX","QXXQQXXXX","XQXQQXXXX","XXQQQXXXX","XXQQXQXXX","XXQQXXQXX","XXQQXXXQX","XQXQXQXXX","XQXQXXQXX","XQXQXXXQX","QXXQXQXXX","QXXQXXQXX","QXXQXXXQX","QXXXQQXXX","XQXXQQXXX","XXQXQQXXX","XXXQQQXXX","XXXQQXQXX","XXXQQXXQX","XXQXQXQXX","XXQXQXXQX","XQXXQXQXX","XQXXQXXQX","QXXXQXQXX","QXXXQXXQX","QXXXXQQXX","XQXXXQQXX","XXQXXQQXX","XXXQXQQXX","XXXXQQQXX","XXXXQQXQX","XXXQXQXQX","XQXXXQXQX","QXXXXQXQX","XXQXXQXQX","QXXXXXQQX","XQXXXXQQX","XXQXXXQQX","XXXQXXQQX","XXXXQXQQX","XXXXXQQQX"]
```

We can have a faster implementation as well:

```
insertAtEvery x []     = [[x]]
insertAtEvery x (y:ys) = (x:y:ys) : map (y:) (insertAtEvery x ys)

combinations []     = [[]]
combinations (x:xs) = nub . concatMap (insertAtEvery x) . combinations $ xs
```

Comparison with the previous solution in ghci:

```
Prelude Data.List> (sort . nub . permutations $ "XXXXXXQQQ") == (sort . combinations $ "XXXXXXQQQ")
True
Prelude Data.List> :set +s
Prelude Data.List> combinations "XXXXXXQQQ"
["XXXXXXQQQ","XXXXXQXQQ","XXXXXQQXQ","XXXXXQQQX","XXXXQXXQQ","XXXXQXQXQ","XXXXQXQQX","XXXXQQXXQ","XXXXQQXQX","XXXXQQQXX","XXXQXXXQQ","XXXQXXQXQ","XXXQXXQQX","XXXQXQXXQ","XXXQXQXQX","XXXQXQQXX","XXXQQXXXQ","XXXQQXXQX","XXXQQXQXX","XXXQQQXXX","XXQXXXXQQ","XXQXXXQXQ","XXQXXXQQX","XXQXXQXXQ","XXQXXQXQX","XXQXXQQXX","XXQXQXXXQ","XXQXQXXQX","XXQXQXQXX","XXQXQQXXX","XXQQXXXXQ","XXQQXXXQX","XXQQXXQXX","XXQQXQXXX","XXQQQXXXX","XQXXXXXQQ","XQXXXXQXQ","XQXXXXQQX","XQXXXQXXQ","XQXXXQXQX","XQXXXQQXX","XQXXQXXXQ","XQXXQXXQX","XQXXQXQXX","XQXXQQXXX","XQXQXXXXQ","XQXQXXXQX","XQXQXXQXX","XQXQXQXXX","XQXQQXXXX","XQQXXXXXQ","XQQXXXXQX","XQQXXXQXX","XQQXXQXXX","XQQXQXXXX","XQQQXXXXX","QXXXXXXQQ","QXXXXXQXQ","QXXXXXQQX","QXXXXQXXQ","QXXXXQXQX","QXXXXQQXX","QXXXQXXXQ","QXXXQXXQX","QXXXQXQXX","QXXXQQXXX","QXXQXXXXQ","QXXQXXXQX","QXXQXXQXX","QXXQXQXXX","QXXQQXXXX","QXQXXXXXQ","QXQXXXXQX","QXQXXXQXX","QXQXXQXXX","QXQXQXXXX","QXQQXXXXX","QQXXXXXXQ","QQXXXXXQX","QQXXXXQXX","QQXXXQXXX","QQXXQXXXX","QQXQXXXXX","QQQXXXXXX"]
(0.01 secs, 3,135,792 bytes)
Prelude Data.List> nub $ permutations "XXXXXXQQQ"
["XXXXXXQQQ","QXXXXXXQQ","XQXXXXXQQ","XXQXXXXQQ","XXXQXXXQQ","XXXXQXXQQ","XXXXXQXQQ","QQXXXXXXQ","QXQXXXXXQ","QXXQXXXXQ","QXXXQXXXQ","QXXXXQXXQ","QXXXXXQXQ","XQQXXXXXQ","XQXQXXXXQ","XQXXQXXXQ","XQXXXQXXQ","XQXXXXQXQ","XXQQXXXXQ","XXQXQXXXQ","XXQXXQXXQ","XXQXXXQXQ","XXXQQXXXQ","XXXQXQXXQ","XXXQXXQXQ","XXXXQQXXQ","XXXXQXQXQ","XXXXXQQXQ","QQQXXXXXX","QQXQXXXXX","QQXXQXXXX","QQXXXQXXX","QQXXXXQXX","QQXXXXXQX","QXQQXXXXX","XQQQXXXXX","XQQXQXXXX","XQQXXQXXX","XQQXXXQXX","XQQXXXXQX","QXQXQXXXX","QXQXXQXXX","QXQXXXQXX","QXQXXXXQX","QXXQQXXXX","XQXQQXXXX","XXQQQXXXX","XXQQXQXXX","XXQQXXQXX","XXQQXXXQX","XQXQXQXXX","XQXQXXQXX","XQXQXXXQX","QXXQXQXXX","QXXQXXQXX","QXXQXXXQX","QXXXQQXXX","XQXXQQXXX","XXQXQQXXX","XXXQQQXXX","XXXQQXQXX","XXXQQXXQX","XXQXQXQXX","XXQXQXXQX","XQXXQXQXX","XQXXQXXQX","QXXXQXQXX","QXXXQXXQX","QXXXXQQXX","XQXXXQQXX","XXQXXQQXX","XXXQXQQXX","XXXXQQQXX","XXXXQQXQX","XXXQXQXQX","XQXXXQXQX","QXXXXQXQX","XXQXXQXQX","QXXXXXQQX","XQXXXXQQX","XXQXXXQQX","XXXQXXQQX","XXXXQXQQX","XXXXXQQQX"]
(0.71 secs, 161,726,128 bytes)
```

Comment: Since `permutations` will generate (n+m)! Strings and `nub` is quadratic in input size, this is spectacularly inefficient: `O(((n+m)!)^2)`. Add just one extra X or Q and it hangs for a while - I stopped it after a couple seconds.